# Python Django Download Model as Excel File

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have database with some data and I want to download it as an excel file. In other words, how can I programmatically convert my model to an excel file when I hit the download button on my app?

Comment: start with writing some code and show it to us!

Comment: I don't know where can I start, my model is ready and I thought that it is not necessary to post.

Comment: download as csv file is probably a good start

Answer (score 4):

Use the excellent xlsxwriter library.  I've used it from django, it's remarkably
easy.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import xlsxwriter

def returnexcel():
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mymodel.xlsx"'

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(response, {'in_memory': True})

# add a worksheet

    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write_... 

# use xlsxwriter routines to create the worksheet

# now write it out
    workbook.close()
    return response
```

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html